# Can't deploy backend as CaaS on back4app

Tags: back4app

Now I have backend that use websocket server.
I am depoying it on back4app but when run "yarn run" command in deploying process on back4app, following error occured.

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]

2023-06-07T17:20:56.002Z
INFO
No files changed in this command, skipping snapshotting.

2023-06-07T17:21:00.000Z
INFO
Pushed registry.containers.back4app.com/back4app2-ebfe0731-023e-4a58-b5cb-fa424c74f5e8/cache@sha256:bc0cd2735ce537b1ff2f4ca118410561931fa5196788e7234b3271220fd51c91

2023-06-07T17:21:00.001Z
INFO
Pushing image to registry.containers.back4app.com/back4app2-ebfe0731-023e-4a58-b5cb-fa424c74f5e8:3fece98e-2d0e-46bd-9ac2-46e3e6ba80cd

2023-06-07T17:21:07.000Z
INFO
Pushed registry.containers.back4app.com/back4app2-ebfe0731-023e-4a58-b5cb-fa424c74f5e8@sha256:70462bcd4f57ce485ae70a30e2ae93eece99db520a7244af69fd7a5852211eaa

2023-06-07T17:21:08.711Z
SYSTEM
LAUNCHING CONTAINER...

2023-06-07T17:21:22.796Z
SYSTEM
CHECKING HEALTH...

2023-06-07T17:21:22.797Z
SYSTEM
trying to hit the 3000 port using http

2023-06-07T17:21:22.802Z
SYSTEM
it looks that no process is listening to the 3000 port using http

2023-06-07T17:21:22.807Z
SYSTEM
trying again in 1s

2023-06-07T17:21:23.807Z
SYSTEM
trying to hit the 3000 port using http

2023-06-07T17:21:23.810Z
SYSTEM
it looks that no process is listening to the 3000 port using http

2023-06-07T17:21:23.812Z
SYSTEM
trying again in 2s

I change backend port as 3000 but still error exists.
This is first deploy for me. I have deployed this backend server on cloud yet.

Comment: Are you able to run the same project locally? If so, I'd recommend contact their team, and they will help you with that.